# How to execute "collapse-all-folds" in the MATLAB editor programatically?

Tags: java, matlab, netbeans, matlab-java

I've been struggling with the problem in the subject for a bit longer than I'd like to admit.

I'm attempting to programatically execute the same `Action` that occurs when the user either clicks on the `View` > `Collapse All` button or right-clicks within the editor window and then `Code Folding` > `Fold All`.

**What I tried\found so far:**

- The `String` that corresponds to the `Action` may be found in the `enum` `com.mathworks.mde.editor.ActionID` and is: `'collapse-all-folds'`.
- When the `Action` activates, the following method seems to be executed: `org.netbeans.api.editor.fold.FoldUtilities.collapseAll(...)` (hence the netbeans tag).
- This code allows me to get instances of `EditorAction`, `ActionManager`, `MatlabEditor`:

```
jEd = com.mathworks.mlservices.MLEditorServices.getEditorApplication.getActiveEditor;
jAm = com.mathworks.mde.editor.ActionManager(jEd);
jAc = com.mathworks.mde.editor.EditorAction('collapse-all-folds');
```

My problem is that I can't find a way to actually *activate* the `Action`.

Any ideas / alternatives?

---

**EDIT1**: After digging a bit in ["the book"](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/matlab-java-book), I think I came even closer than before (but still not quite there). Quoting from the book:

> *Java GUI components often use an`ActionMap`to store runnable`Actions`that are
>   invoked by listeners on mouse, keyboard, property, or container events. Unlike object methods,`Actions`cannot be directly invoked by MATLAB.*

And then a workaround is explained which involves roughly: getting some sort of an `Action` object; creating an `ActionEvent` and invoking `Action`'s `actionPerformed`   with the `ActionEvent` as an argument, as implemented below:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
jEd = com.mathworks.mlservices.MLEditorServices.getEditorApplication.getActiveEditor;
jAm = com.mathworks.mde.editor.ActionManager(jEd);
jAc = jAm.getAction(com.mathworks.mde.editor.EditorAction('collapse-all-folds'));
jAe = ActionEvent(jAm, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, '');
jAc.actionPerformed(jAe);
```

This code runs without errors - but does (seemingly?) nothing. I suspect that I'm calling `ActionEvent` and `actionPerformed` on the wrong objects (`ActionManager` has possibly nothing to do with this problem at all).

---

P.S.

I know that there's a hotkey that does this (`Ctrl` + `=`), but this is not what I'm looking for <strike>(unless there's a command to simulate a hotkey press :) ).</strike>

Comment: Perhaps @YairAltman will hear this call and answer.

Comment: @Sam - Hehe... Nice try :)

Comment: Ahhhh! Thanks for the hotkey !! That is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After immeasurable digging, trial and way too much error - I've done it!

```
function FullyCollapseCurrentScript()

%// Get the relevant javax.swing.text.JTextComponent:
jTc = com.mathworks.mlservices.MLEditorServices ...
        .getEditorApplication.getActiveEditor.getTextComponent();
%// Get the FoldHierarchy for the JTextComponent:
jFh = org.netbeans.api.editor.fold.FoldHierarchy.get(jTc);
%// Finally, collapse every possible fold:
org.netbeans.api.editor.fold.FoldUtilities.collapseAll(jFh);

end
```

or if compressed into a single, messy, command:

```
org.netbeans.api.editor.fold.FoldUtilities.collapseAll(...
org.netbeans.api.editor.fold.FoldHierarchy.get(com.mathworks. ...
mlservices.MLEditorServices.getEditorApplication.getActiveEditor. ...
getTextComponent()));
```

Note that this works on the script currently open in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

**Not a perfect solution** but simulating the default hotkey press with `java.awt.robot` is possible.

*...finding a way to actually fire the Action directly would be better...*

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.*;
RoboKey = Robot;

jTextComp = com.mathworks.mlservices.MLEditorServices. ... 
        getEditorApplication.getActiveEditor.getTextComponent;


jTextComp.grabFocus()
drawnow;            %// give time for focus


if jTextComp.hasFocus()
    RoboKey.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    RoboKey.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS);

    RoboKey.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    RoboKey.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS);

    com.mathworks.mde.cmdwin.CmdWin.getInstance.grabFocus;  %// focus back to cmdwin

else
    warning('Failed to collapse folds: Editor could not take focus')
end
```

Comment: I saw this sort of solution somewhere (I believe [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/243113)), but was hoping for something much more compact.