# call different sections of the code by call

Tags: matlab

Consider the following example

```
%%
a = 1:10;
%%
b = 11:20;
%%
c = 21:30
```

It is divided into 3 sections and I can call each section with `Alt`+`Shift`+`X`seperately 
but what If i want to call each section by call for example another file

```
testloadfile
d = a*5;
```

loads this data but it only needs `a` to use so calling the whole file would be waste of time and memory 
can I call a specified section of code by call ? or it isnt possible

Comment: it isnt possible.  Also, I do call each part with CTRL+ENTER

Comment: The recommended way here would be to avoid the use of scripts and instead use a function for each of the values that you need.

Comment: @Suever The problem is the script I want to use is already there and is pretty huge and load a big amount of data I want to load just a few sections in it

Answer (score 0):

Somebody else answered this question here: [Run particular cell section from command line in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970619/run-particular-cell-section-from-command-line-in-matlab)

There is no native solution in Matlab to do what you ask. The linked answer uses a custom Matlab class to load the script and run particular code sections. Here is the code from the link (not written by me):

```
classdef cellRunner < handle
  properties ( SetAccess = private )
    fileName
    fileInfo
    cellInfo
    cellNames = {};
  end
  methods 
    function obj = cellRunner ( file ) % constructor
      if nargin == 0                        
        obj.fileName = 'cellScript.m';      % default file for testing
      else
        obj.fileName = file;                % store user file
      end
      obj.parseFile();                      % read the file into memory
    end
    function obj = parseFile ( obj )
      if ~isempty ( obj.fileInfo )                        % on parsing check to see if its been parsed before
        if isequal ( obj.fileInfo, dir ( obj.fileName ) ) % Check date stamp (has cell file been modified
%           disp ( 'file not changed - reading skipped' );  % if not skip
%           reading 
          return
        end
      end
      obj.fileInfo = dir ( obj.fileName );                % store file info
      fid = fopen ( obj.fileName );                       % open file for reading
      if fid ~= -1
        index = 0;                                        % this is the index of each cell
        inCell = false;                                   % has it found a cell to start reading
        lines = cell(0);                                  
        while ( true )
          line = fgetl ( fid );                           % read the line in the file
          if line == -1; break; end                       % check for the end of the file
          sLine = strtrim ( line );                       % trim any white space
          if length ( sLine ) > 2 && strcmp ( sLine(1:2), '%%' ) % check to see if its the start of a cell
            if index > 0                                  % Store the last cell data                
              obj.cellInfo{index} = lines;                % in class to run when required
            end
            index = index + 1;                            % increment the index
            obj.cellNames{index} = strtrim ( sLine(3:end) ); % save the name of the cell
            lines = cell(0);                              % re-initialise the lines var
            inCell = true;                                % the start of the cells have been found
          elseif inCell                                   % if reading a cell array
            lines{end+1} = line;                          % add each line to the lines var
          end          
        end
        if index > 0                                      % make sure and save the last cell when finished reading
          obj.cellInfo{index} = lines;
        end
        fclose ( fid );
      else
        error ( 'cellRunner:fileError', 'unable to read file' );
      end
    end
    function obj = runCell ( obj, arg )
      % obj.runCell ( 'cellName' );
      % obj.runCell ( index );
      obj.parseFile();                                    % check that the file hasn't been changed
      if ischar ( arg )                                   % if user provided a char then search for it
        index = strcmp ( arg, obj.cellNames );            % find the index
        if ~any ( index )                                 % check it was found
          error ( 'cellRunner:notFound', '%s not found', arg ); 
        end
      else
        index = arg;                                      % if index is an integer (not checked - assumed if not char)
        if index < 1 || index > length ( obj.cellInfo )   % check integer is valid
          error ( 'cellRunner:notFound', 'Index %d not found', arg );
        end
      end
      commands = obj.cellInfo{index}{1};                  % start to build the command to execute.
      inBlock = false;
      for ii=2:length(obj.cellInfo{index})                % loop around - ignoring any commented lines.
        nextLine = strtrim ( obj.cellInfo{index}{ii} ); 
        if inBlock
          if length ( nextLine ) == 2 && strcmp ( nextLine, '%}' );
            inBlock = false;
          end
          continue
        end
        if length ( nextLine ) == 2 && strcmp ( nextLine, '%{' );
          inBlock = true;
          continue
        end
        if length ( nextLine ) >= 1 && strcmp ( nextLine(1), '%' )
          continue;
        end
        commands = sprintf ( '%s;%s', commands, obj.cellInfo{index}{ii} ); % build a parge string to eval
      end
      evalin('base',commands);                            % eval the expression in the base workspace.
    end
  end
end
```

If you name your script "myscript.m" and label your sections, you can use the above class as follows:

```
obj = cellRunner('myscript.m');
obj.runCell ( 'cellA' );
```

You can also use the block index like so

```
obj.runCell ( 3 );
```

Variables created in the code cells will be in the workspace just like if you had run them yourself

Comment: The whole point of doing the above task is to save time again and again by not pressing alt shift X , by restructuring my whole code it would be the same amount of effort

Comment: How is this not an answer? The link I provided answers the exact question. I would mark the question as duplicate if I knew how. But going to that link, copying the code therein and using it will achieve what the question intended. With the code in the link, you can call individual matlab code sections